# Find Minimum Value in a Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table column containing integers.  What's the most efficient way to get the minimum value using JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 8):

Using jQuery, you could [use the `.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) with [the `.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get an Array of integers, [then `.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) the Array as the arguments [for `Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to get the minimum.

This assumes that you want the first column in the table. Selector may need to change depending on which column you want.

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/iyiqa3/

```
var values = $('#myTable tr > td:first-child').map(function() {
    return parseInt( $.text( [this] ) );
}).get();

var minimum = Math.min.apply( null, values );
```

Without jQuery, try this:

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/iyiqa3/2/

```
var values = [];

var trs = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');

for( var i = 0, len = trs.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    values.push( parseInt( trs[ i ].cells[ 0 ].innerHTML ) );
}

var minimum = Math.min.apply( null, values );
```

Comment: +1 for using `apply()` to pass an array into `Math.min()`... clever.

Answer (score 1):

Non-jquery answer (and no guarantees it is "the most" efficient, but shouldn't be bad):

```
var min, rowNo = null;

var a = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
 var td = a[i].childNodes[columnNo];
 var val = parseInt(td.innerHTML);
 if (rowNo == null || val < min) {
  min = val;
  rowNo = i;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with plain JavaScript, run through each row of the table, look at the column you're interested in and find the minimum:

```
function getColumnMin(tableId, columnIndex) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  var min = Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    var value = (cols[columnIndex].firstChild.nodeValue | 0); // force to integer value
    if (value < min)
      min = value;
  }
  return min;
}
```

This assumes that each `<td>` contains exactly one value and no other HTML tags.

Comment: The nodeValue of every td is null.

Comment: @kennebec: Oops, forgot `firstChild`. Thanks.